# same session ID being generated across different IE windows

Tags: session, internet-explorer-8

I have observed on IE 8 windows 7 machine, whenever I open my application on separate IE windows, the same session ID gets generated for each of them.

I was expecting different session ID's for different windows.

Does anyone knows why this is happening.

Code used to generate session ID

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things changed between IE7 and IE8 with regard to how new sessions are created. In IE8, choose File > New Session to create a new browser session.

You should read my article on this topic: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/04/05/understanding-browser-session-lifetime.aspx

Comment: Sweet! But is there a workaround on this for ASP.Net? Like, whenever the user does not choose File > New Session?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Internet Explorer windows (and tabs) share the same process (assuming you opened the second window from within Internet Explorer), and therefore have the same cookies. Since your session ID is likely being stored in a cookie, this is why you get the same session ID for multiple windows.

Running separate Internet Explorer processes (or using IE plus another browser) should allow you to simulate multiple sessions.

Comment: thanks Anthony for your comments. But isn't this behavior different for IE7? In IE7 a new window will always result in a new session unlike IE8.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure which version of Internet Explorer this functionality changed in, but I do know that older versions of IE used to result in one session per window. Not sure whether IE7 is on that list though.